# Copy Constructor with Java Interface

Tags: java

I have a class that has a collection of interfaces and I need to clone this object. I do not want to use the clone interface and want to do things with copy constructors. I did some googling around and couldn't seem to find the answer to this. I realize there are other ways to do this with a copy method for example, but I'd prefer to not add that to my interface. Thanks for your help.

```
public Component(Component source){
for (Behavior behavior : behaviors) {
  behaviors.add(new Behavior(behavior));
 }}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't add constructors to an interface.  This can't be done.

Your instinct to avoid Cloneable is a good one.  You might need a virtual factory method to decide the concrete type of the common interface to return.

Answer (score 3):

You could either:

1. Add a copy method to the `Behavior` interface, so that each implementation can choose what to return (it could even be the instance itself if it's immutable, see point 2 below).
2. Require that a `Behavior` is immutable, so you don't need to copy it. That's arguably difficult to enforce, though.
3. Make `Behavior` an (abstract) class, and add a copy constructor to it. This may be a flaw in your hierarchy, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define constructors in interfaces, so you must either use clone, or a copy method.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the cleanest way would be to override Object's `clone()` method for each of Behavior interface implementations.